# How to get data from firebase with kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I can get data from a rest api using Kotlin coroutines but failed for firebase

Car.kt

```
data class Car (
var carID : Long,
var carBrand : String,
var carModel : String,
var price :  Double,
var status : Boolean,
var carImage: String
)
```

MainActivity.kt

```
val y = MyClass()

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {

        carList = y.getCars()     //is working

        for(car in carList!!){
            car.carImage = y.getCarImage(database,car.carID).
                    .toString()      //get data from firebase
        }
```

MyClass.kt

```
 //working   (the problem is not here) 
 //I wanted to show that 'await' works here
  suspend fun getCars(): List<Car>? {
    val carRequest = service.getCarss().await()


    if (carRequest.isSuccessful) {
        val carList = carRequest.body()
        return carList
    } else {
        return null
    }
}


//not working  
suspend fun getCarImage(database: FirebaseFirestore,carID: Long) : Task<QuerySnapshot>? {
    return try{
        var Url: String
        val data = database
                .collection("carImage")
                .whereEqualTo("carID",carID).get().await()  
        data
    }catch (e : Exception){
        null
    }
}
```

i have "unresolved reference await" error message on 'getCarImage' function

When I try to access from MainActivity this way, it works, but I want to call MyClass from a function in the class.

```
   database.collection("carImage").whereEqualTo("carID", "4").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
        if (exception != null) {

            Toast.makeText(this, exception.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {

            if (snapshot != null) {

                if (!snapshot.isEmpty) {


                    val documents = snapshot.documents

                    for (document in documents) {
                     Url = document.get("carUrl") as String
                        println(Url)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Change `.get().await()` to `.await()`. Also, you should avoid using GlobalScope and instead use `lifecycleScope` or a locally-created scope. https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc

Comment: changes did not work. the same error continues @Tenfour04

Comment: Sorry, I'm leading you down the wrong path. You do need the `get()` call to get a Task. Task does have an `await()` function, but it is probably an extension function  included in a separate dependency you need to put in your build.gradle file. I don't use Firebase so I don't know 100%. But wherever you have Firebase dependencies in your `build.gradle` file, make sure you put `-ktx` in the name right before the colon and version number.

Comment: I checked them out. the problem is not here. I can access rest api but it failed with firebase @Tenfour04